# Conversion of a small XML containfg different data values to POJO

Tags: java, xml

I am currently writing a parser for a simple XML. The XML at its longest contains 18 lines. I am trying to parse it and convert it to a POJO. I know that I can use JAXB or similar libraries, but I felt that considering the size of the XML, that would be an overkill. Also, this is an exercise to think beyond libraries.

An example XML would be:

```
<machineinfo>
    <processorCount>4</processorCount>
    <boughtDate>2014-06-09 23:17:49.0</boughtDate>
    <installationStatus>COMPLETE</installationStatus>
    <machineType>BASIC</machineType>
    <osVersion>1849AB48DOED</osVersion>
    <serverName>fjv920dk</serverName>
    <machineStatus>UP</machineStatus>
    <statusPay1>NA</statusPay1>
    <statusPay2>NA</statusPay2>
    <errorCode>NO_ERROR</errorCode>
    <exceptionCode>0</exceptionCode>
    <isCloneable>true</isCloneable>
    <latestVersion>1849AB48DOED</latestVersion>
    <mastermachineName/>
    <podName>8D2</podName>
    <machineName>machine2</machineName>
</machineinfo>
```

My core conversion logic is as follows:

```
if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("processorCount")) {
    machineInfo.setProcessorCount(new Integer(data).intValue());
} else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("boughtDate")) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(data);
    machineInfo.setBoughtDate(dt);
} else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("installationStatus") {
    machineInfo.setInstallationStatus(InstallationStatus.valueOf(data));
} else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("installationStatus") {
    machineInfo.setInstallationStatus(InstallationStatus.valueOf(data));
}
```

As you can see, this leads to multiple `if` conditions. I tried simplifying that by using a `Map` as follows:

```
Map <String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("machineName", data);
map.put("machineType", data);
String mapValue = (String) map.get(tagName);
```

But how do I determine which setter in `machineInfo` should be invoked?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Java Reflection or Java Beans API for that.

I like to invoke dynamic setters using `PropertyDescriptor`:

```
Method writerMethod = new PropertyDescriptor(fieldName, MachineInfo.class).getWriteMethod();
writerMethod.invoke(machineInstance, fieldValue);
```

Refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.html

Regards,
Bruno

Comment: This works for cases where the `value` was `String`. However, it fails in other cases.

Comment: Yes, you must cast "fieldValue" for the targeted setter. Maybe you can have a Map for each type?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the following snippet:

```
ConvertUtilsBean convertUtilsBean = new ConvertUtilsBean();
convertUtilsBean.deregister(DateTime.class);
convertUtilsBean.register(new JodaDateTimeConverter(), DateTime.class);
BeanUtilsBean beanUtilsBean = new BeanUtilsBean(convertUtilsBean, new PropertyUtilsBean());

try {
    beanUtilsBean.setProperty(machineInfo, qName, temp);
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And by creating the following converter:

```
class JodaDateTimeConverter implements Converter {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.apache.commons.beanutils.Converter#convert(java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object)
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T convert(Class<T> arg0, Object arg1) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime((String) arg1);
        return (T) dt;
    }
}
```